# Angular.js Call $http.get from outside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an HTTP resource that returns a JSON list of top 10 entities from a database.
I call it this way:

```
var filter= "john";
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('SearchController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/api/Entity/Find/' + filter). //Get entities filtered
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.entities = data;
        }).
        error(function () {
        });
    }]);
```

It works!

But... how can I change the `filter` variable in order to change the query?
Should I rewrite the whole controller to get this to work?

## Update

Sorry for the lack of clarity in my question. When I asked this I couldn't undertand anything of AngularJS.

My original intent was to get the variable `$http` injected, without relying on creating a controller for that.

Thanks for everyone.

Comment: Not really clear what you're trying to do generally speaking you want to use a service to handle communicating with your server most of the time.  That said it's just not clear what you want to have happen.

Comment: I presume you are having restful call where you can add filters, based on actions in your page, you can write a function to modify the filter value and hence change the url to fetch . Explain complete scenario to get clear answer. maybe a jsfiddle or plunker

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## A likely better method

If you don't want to get it inside a controller, you could have it injected into a recipe (ex, provider, factory, service):
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

```
myApp.factory('getStuff', ['filter', '$http', function (filter, $http) {
    //Blah
}]);
```

#### If you want to get an instance of $http outside of any angular struct, you can do what's shown below.

The method given by Dennis works; however, it does not work if called before angular has been bootstrapped.  Also, it seems like Derek has an error with Dennis' method because he does not have jquery.

The solution that Exlord mentioned is better, as it does not have that problem, and is more proper:

```
$http = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$http");
```

**Explained:**

The angular injector is an:

> object that can be used for retrieving services as well as for dependency injection

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector

The function angular.injector takes the modules as a parameter and returns an instance of the injector.

So in this case you retrieve an injector for the ng module (angular's), and then retrieve the service $http.

**Note:**
One thing to keep in mind when using injector like this is that in my own findings it seems you need to make sure you include modules in the inject which what you are "getting" will need.  For example:

```
angular.injector(['ng', 'ngCordova']).get('$cordovaFileTransfer')
```

Comment: I love my original typo when I said "because he does not have javascript".  I think Derek should have an error with my method as well, if he did not have JavaScript ;)  I've since corrected to "he does not have jquery"

Comment: I love how you apologize for a great answer :) +1

Comment: Getting modules this way seems to be really slow for me and causes my app to not load data until the next refresh.

Comment: @sudoman "Until the next refresh"?  Perhaps it's an issue with the modules you're using.  I just did a performance test, and I can call it 1000 times in about half a second: https://plnkr.co/edit/aXQiHENdb7Pp3VY8BhKe?p=preview

Comment: Getting it through a controller seems faster, I decided to pass it as a parameter to a function from the controller.

Comment: @daka Yes, that is the best way to do it for sure.  But his original question specifically asked how to access $http outside of the controller.

Comment: @csga5000 I ended up using Factories, its much faster

Comment: @daka The cases I used the injector were pretty oddball when I wanted to do an HTTP request outside of angular without including jquery - which probably indicates you're being sloppy, but I think it was an Isolated thing I didn't want to deal with.  I added a note about factories accordingly

Answer (score 8):

Regarding to your question "... call $http.get from outside controller" you can do the following:

```
... ANYWHERE IN YOUR CODE

var $http = angular.element('html').injector().get('$http');
$http.get(...).success(...);

ANYWHERE IN YOUR CODE ...
```

See official docs from angular: [angular $injector docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector) : 
The `get(name);` method `Returns an instance of the service.`

Comment: this only works after the angular app has been bootstraped and not before that

Comment: this is the correct way but this works `var $http = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$http");`

Comment: My site does not use jQuery, so I got this error: "Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!"  Exlord's syntax worked, however.

Comment: @DerekKurth obviously a little late, but see my answer