# $http.get is undefined when $http is used outside angular code

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angularjs-controller, angularjs-http

I am running jasmine unit test against a method which is outside angular controller.

Running the jasmine throws the following error,

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined at testMethod

Can anyone help me with fixing the above error. Thanks !

**Test.js**

```
function testMethod() {
    var $http = angular.element('html').injector().get('$http');
    $http.get('/testAPI/testCall').success(...);
}
```

**TestSpec.js**

```
it('makes a successful Test call', angular.mock.inject(function ($http, $window) {
    testMethod();
}));
```

**JasmineSpecRunner.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine_favicon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jasmine.css">

<script src="lib/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>

<script src="lib/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="lib/boot.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-mocks.js"></script>

<!-- include source files here-->
<script src="src/Test.js"></script>

<!-- include spec files here-->
<script src="specs/TestSpec.js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="SpecRunner" ng-controller="SpecController"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: My implementation is based on this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051335/angular-js-call-http-get-from-outside-controller) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to inject $http  in the testMethod function.. like this testMethod($http).

Also, I think you have spelling mistake in this line:

```
<script src="specs/TestSpec.js.js"></script>
```

it should be like this:

```
<script src="specs/TestSpec.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using httpBackend service of angular mocks for testing ajax calls to server.